# SSIS Excel Source Dynamic column name and column size

Tags: ssis

I have excel files. None of these column names and column numbers are equal. I want the folder to receive that data as the file is uploaded unconditionally. How can I do it .

Comment: What are you doing with the Excel files?  By "folder" do you mean "SQL Table?"

Answer (score 1):

Solved. 
If you experience such a problem, check the link below

https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/ssis-importing-a-file-with-dynamic-columns/